# How to save data when app is running in background?

Tags: iphone, background, gps, location

I am new in iOS developer. Now I am working at a background location app. I need to send data to server and save some info from feedback. First time I save the data in UIKit class, but it seems released. Second time I save the data in static variables. It still crash. Then I have to use NSUserDefaults , it works . But is this OK? Any better way? Save data to local or something else ? Thanks~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better way is to use NSUserDefaults, you save your data there and you dont worry about the data been released or removed.

Another way is global data or singletons, but is not recommended by Apple (you can find a lot of discussions about this in the internet)

I personally recommend you to use NSUserDefaults, if you have any doubt using it we can help you.